# Eliminar elemento de una lista en python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

No se bien en que me estoy equivocando, tengo el concepto pero me confunde aun un poco

```
def eliminarEnLista(L):
   n=int(raw_input("Ingrese el numero que desea eliminar de la lista: "))       
   L=[]    
   i=0    
   while i <len(L): 
      for cont in L[i]:
          if cont <=L[i]:
              continue
          if cont==n and cont==L[i]:
              L.remove(i)
          else:
             pass
      i+=1

   return L
```

No me imprime nada en pantalla despues de llamar esta funcion y quisiera saber cual es mi problema u_u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay varias cosas mal en tu función.

1. Pasas una lista, L, por parámetro, pero la asignas a L una lista vacía, por lo que pierdes la lista.
2. Dejando a un lado que hagas dos bucles anidados, que para este problema no es necesario, en el bucle for intentas recorrer L[i]. Suponiendo que la lista L sea de números (lo supongo por el raw_input), L[i] será un número, por lo cual no puedes iterar sobre él, y en esta sentencia fallaría el programa.
3. Si no quieres hacer nada si se incumple el if, no hace falta que hagas un else. Poner else para hacer pass es completamente innecesario.
4. `remove` no elimina por indice, si no por el elemento de la lista, por lo que no tendrías que recorrer la lista en ningún momento.

Un ejemplo de como podrías hacerlo es el siguiente. Ten en cuenta que la lista que pasas por parámetro será modificada.

```
def eliminarEnLista(L):
    n=int(raw_input("Ingrese el numero que desea eliminar de la lista: "))
    try:
        L.remove(n)
        print(L)
    except ValueError:
        print('{} no se encuentra en la lista'.format(n))
L = [1,2,3]
eliminarEnLista(L)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, este lenguaje es nuevo para mi y recien voy entendiendo , de verdad muchas gracias ^^... disculpa las molestias pero en caso de que el numero que se desea eliminar este repetido en la lista como lo hago para eliminarlo tantas veces se repita?

Answer (score 0):

```
def eliminarEnLista(una_lista):
    posicion = input("¿Qué posición que desea eliminar de la lista: " + ",".join(una_lista) + " ? ")
    if(str(posicion).isdigit() and int(posicion) <= len(una_lista)):
        una_lista.pop(int(posicion))
        return ",".join(una_lista)
    else:
        return "Algo anda mal"

print(eliminarEnLista(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]))
```